# index.php file for custom module

Tags: navigation

i have custom software and wanna write an api for drupal (custom software -> drupal). The thing is the custom software will call api calls to index.php (you cant change that). So how can i write something like an index.php for my module, like (http://drupal.install/myhookmenulink/index.php) so the software can reach that link and send infos to my module. anyone know ?

greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal allows calls to .php files out of the box. Take a look at the .htaccess file and you will see that .php files will be handled just like any php application.

So... just create your .php file and make sure you are including it at the appropriate path.

That all said, in D8 (or in D7 + elbow grease) you get some pretty powerful autoloader capabilities out of the box so ideally you could take advantage of that in your module.

Comment: Small caveat (I'm sure you know this but for others that may not): Drupal doesn't supersede the web server, and it's not uncommon to lock external requests for .php files down to the known 'safe' ones (/index.php, /cron.php, etc), so there's a chance some server config will be needed too. It'll be more relevant if using nginx, for example, where it's considered good practice to lock the fpm proxy down to specific files rather than *.php

Comment: So i should create a index.php file in my module folder and include the bootstrap there ? Then i could make a call to my .module functions.

Comment: It wasn't clear that's what you're trying to do from the original question, but you don't need to bootstrap anything. Just implement `hook_menu()` with a path of "path/to/index.php" and you'll have a fully bootstrapped Drupal in the callback as normal. Going out of Drupal and back in again would be a wasted step here, `hook_menu` routes can have extensions in them

Comment: oh ok i understand, thx a lot :)